# How to create layered navigation for a custom product collection?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working on a custom module to show all products with a custom attribute. I got the result into a list area, but now I am suffering with layered navigation. How can I set layered navigation for a custom product collection?

Comment: looks like it 'moved' here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/57535/6291